# Spring Boot: Design a service that caches timed data

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, caching

I am developing a service using Spring Boot (with Java) and I have the following requirement:
The service (when invoked) must generate a **timed UUID associated with a string** that I pass as input to the service.
For example, if I invoke the service like this (with a Http GET):

http://localhost:8080/myService?param=example

The service returns me a UUID like 55bcbfce-8984-4f1d-8435-f9548baf8cb5.
The fact is that I want to implement a caching system that stores (for a limited time, like 5 seconds) this UUID along with the passed string `example`.

So, a "table" stored in the application would be such a thing like this:

| UUID | param | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55bcbfce-8984-4f1d-8435-f9548baf8cb5 | `example` | 3sec |
| 07ef2e6e-e6a1-45e7-b6a6-51dfab49f782 | `example2` | 2sec |

Like this, a second service I call by passing it a UUID as input, like this:

http://localhost:8080/mySecondService?UUID=55bcbfce-8984-4f1d-8435-f9548baf8cb5

It could return me (**if invoked in the right time**) the `param` associated with the UUID 55bcbfce-8984-4f1d-8435-f9548baf8cb5, that is `example`. If the time is up, then the second service returns an error.

My question is: is there an easy way to implement this **WITHOUT USING A DB**, but using just a small caching system (the memory will be shared between the two services!)? I am new to both Spring Boot and caching, and have never used cache before. I simply cannot use a DB in this situation.

Comment: Will the services share the same JVM ?

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a DTO like this:

```java
public record ResultDTO(String param, int seconds) {
}
```

You can use `@Cacheable` annotation that handles automatically the cache by configuring a `CacheManager`. You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial).
At the end the method will something like this:

```java
@Cacheable("params")
public ResultDTO getByUUID(String UUID) {
    // your logic to retrieve the object
}
```

The code inside `getByUUID` is executed if the element having `UUID` input is not in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a in memory cache implementation. A cache stores some data temporarily and typically has a feature that automatically removes data (expires) after some time duration.

Here is an example with [cache2k](https://cache2k.org):

```
    Cache<String, String> cache =
      Cache2kBuilder.of(String.class, String.class)
        .entryCapacity(5000)
        .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

    String myService(String param) {
      String uuid = generateUuid();
      cache.put(uuid, param);
    }

    String mySecondService(String uuid) {
      String param = cache.get(uuid);
      if (param == null) {
          // error
      }
      return param;
    }
```

With the code above the expiry is not happening exactly after 5 seconds but may lag around a second depending on system activity. If you want the item to be visible no more than 5 seconds, use this instead of `expireAfterWrite`:

```
  .expiryPolicy((key, value, startTime, currentEntry) ->
    Expiry.toSharpTime(startTime + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)))
```

Make sure to make the entry capacity high enough, because otherwise the cache will evict data was not used recently.

Do not use `@Cacheable` of Spring. It would only fit for `mySecondService` and not for the population of the cache. So don't mix different API concepts.

The approach is basically the same with other cache implementations.